# imprimir un dato obtenido desde un combobox angular

Tags: django, angular

estoy usando un combobox que saque desde el angular material y me gustaria que un textbox saliera un dato, segun la opcion seleccionada del combobox imprimiera algo en el textbox un dato de esa tabla, por ejemplo que en una tabla usuario tener los datos id , nombre , apellido . al seleccionar un id que se muestra en el combobox mostrar en un textbox el nombre relacionado con ese id del usuario ne este caso .

este es el componente ts

```
examenes: Observable<string[]>;
examen = new Examen();
pacientes:Paciente[];
categorias: Categoria[];
getPacientes(): void {
    this.dataService
      .getPacientes()
      .then(pacientes => this.pacientes = pacientes);
  }
  getCategorias(): void {
    this.dataService
      .getCategorias()
      .then(categorias => this.categorias = categorias);
  }
    redirect(){alert("Se Agrego Correctamente");
        this.router.navigate(['./examenes'])
    }
    ngOnInit() {  this.getCategorias();
        this.getPacientes();
    }}
```

lo siguente es el combobox con el textbox que quiero usar

```
        <mat-form-field flex>
                    <input matInput
                    [(ngModel)]="examen.nombrePac"
                    #elementDescripcionControl="ngModel"
                    type="text" 
                    name="NombrePac"
                    placeholder="Nombre Paciente"
                    maxlength="30"
                    readonly
                    >
                    <mat-hint alig="start">
                        <span [hidden]="elementDescripcionControl.pristine || !elementDescripcionControl.errors?.required" class="tc-red-600"> Requerido
                        </span>
                    </mat-hint>
                </mat-form-field>
```

```
 <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Listado de Pacientes</mat-label>
  <mat-select  [(ngModel)]="examen.rutPac" name="rutPac">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let pacientes of pacientes" name="rutPac"     [value]="pacientes.rutPac"
              >
      {{pacientes.rutPac}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```